# Bash script to symlink configuration files from git repo into home directory

Tags: bash, git

My goals are to:

1. Do it automatically (without adding a line to my script every time I add or change the location of a config file)
2. The files in the git repo folder should not be hidden, but the symlinks in my home directory should
3. Existing files of the same name should be overwritten, but not directories. For example if I have `config/conf.txt` in my dotfiles repo, it shouldn't overwrite the entire `~/.config` folder, but simply add a link to `conf.txt` inside `~/.config`.

My current solution does these, but it could probably be done better:

```
DOTFILES_DIR="$HOME/dotfiles"

echo -n Creating symlinks...

shopt -s extglob nocaseglob

# Create hidden symlinks, hard link them to $HOME, rm old symlinks
for dotfile in $DOTFILES_DIR/!(readme*|${0##*/}); do
    hidden="$DOTFILES_DIR/.${dotfile##*/}"
    cp -asf "$dotfile" "$hidden"
    cp -alf "$hidden" "$HOME"
    rm -r "$hidden"
done

echo done
```

I think I should be able to copy the files directly to the home directory, but I had some trouble getting that to work right if a destination folder already existed.

**Edit:** I was able to eliminate the second for loop. Much better. There may still be a better way, though.

Comment: Do not that `cp` is for copying, not symlinking (look at `ln`)

Comment: `cp -s` creates symlinks. I use `cp` because the `-a` option preserves the directory structure (point 3 above)

Comment: Interesting... need to go read my man pages again!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of symlinks I would probably arrange for

```
$ make -C $HOME/dotfiles  refresh
```

to perform some name mangling and `rsync -av` copying,
or perhaps create simpler symlinks without a "hidden" layer.
But you've chosen your favorite approach,
so we'll go down that path.

---

Habitually add these suggested double quotes, please, to control globbing:

```
for dotfile in "$DOTFILES_DIR"/!(readme*|${0##*/}); do
```

(Yes, I know, the source makes it a constant with no SPACE
if `$HOME` lacks whitespace. It's just a good habit to have.)

---

There seems to be more than one file-copying case covered by this code.
The `cp; cp; rm` approach you've chosen is non-intuitive.
I would not be willing to maintain this codebase as presented.
An alternate design would use `find $DIR -type f`
plus a pipeline which mangles filenames and performs
any needed copying.

More `# comments` on the `cp` flag behavior might help.
Automated unit test(s) that demonstrate the code's behavior
would definitely help.
For example, it could show what happens when
`conf.txt` was present for a while, and then
is removed from the `dotfiles` repo.

Comment: Shouldn't `${0##*/}` also be double-quoted?  I don't think we want word-splitting there - or does the `extglob` option somehow prevent that?

Comment: I think likely you're right. In the end, I trust unit tests; they reveal _actual_ behavior. Initially I tried what I knew was dumb, just blindly quoting the whole thing. And `shellcheck` told me I was being dumb, observing that the `for` loop would iterate over just a single item. I feel that defining a `$DIR` directory variable would help with clarity, and that a `find` pipeline which selects or discards certain patterns would also be an improvement. Possibly defined as a brief function. Cramming everything into a one-liner doesn't do future maintainers any favors, as evidenced by our doubts.